# jQuery-UI datepicker doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I was trying to add the jquery UI date picker dynamically. ie when I click on a button, it will create a text field with calendar option... Since Im creating the calendar dynamically, calendar wil not open. 
My code is

```
$("#button").click(function()
{
"<table id='submitReportTable' class = 'OGTable"
                                                + tab_counter
                                                + "'><tr><td><b>PortFolio</b></td><td><select id='portfolio"
                                                + tab_counter
                                                + "'></select></td></tr><tr><td><b>From Date</b></td><td> <input type=text id='datepicker' class='fromDate"
                                                + tab_counter
                                                + "' /></td></tr><tr><td><b>End Date</b></td><td> <input type=text id='datepicker' class='endDate"
                                                + tab_counter
                                                + "' /></td></tr><tr><td><b>Frequncy</b></td><td> <select id='frequency"
                                                + tab_counter
                                                + "'><option>Yearly</option><option>Quarterly</option><option>Monthly</option><option>Weekly</option><option>Daily</option></select></td></tr><tr><td> <input type=button id=submitButton name=submit value='Submit' class='submit"
                                                + tab_counter
                                                + "'></input></td></tr></table>"});
```

this one doesnt get created on button click

Comment: is it inside a document ready block?

Comment: its not inside document.ready...its in another function..

Comment: btw... you know you need to append that HTML to your DOM somewhere... right? Also, -1 cause I feel like I'm helping on a homework of someone that doesn't feel like searching and trying (there are LOADS of examples for this)

Comment: The issue is that I was using multiple datepickers with same dom name...ive fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Thats not even valid jQuery code.  You cannot mix jQuery and html like that. Your code doesn't make any sense:

```
$("#button").click(function()
</td></tr><tr><td><b>From Date</b></td><td>
```

Your button click event handler needs to be valid jQuery and not html.

Comment: ive fixed it... sorry abt the typo..

Comment: @user1371896 not really fixed... your code still does not make sense

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your that adding an input text with id "datepicker" does not do it.
Try calling .datepicker() on your new element as stated in documentation:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: I know that..Ive called the function inside document.ready function

Comment: Something like this? Adding a datepicker when clicking a button http://jsfiddle.net/mPpXn/2/

Answer (score 0):

I have created a working fiddle of what (I think) you are trying to achieve here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Bk9Ut/

When the button is clicked it creates a new input element and then runs the datepicker command on the new element. See documentation here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/ for datepicker information and initialisation options.